# Add/delete row from a table

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have this table with some dependents information and there is a add and delete button for each row to add/delete additional dependents. When I click "add" button, a new row gets added to the table, but when I click the "delete" button, it deletes the header row first and then on subsequent clicking, it deletes the corresponding row.

Here is what I have:

Javascript code

```
   function deleteRow(row){
      var d = row.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
      document.getElementById('dsTable').deleteRow(d);
   }
```

HTML code

```
<table id = 'dsTable' >
      <tr>
         <td> Relationship Type </td>
         <td> Date of Birth </td>
         <td> Gender </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td> Spouse </td>
         <td> 1980-22-03 </td>
         <td> female </td>
         <td> <input type="button" id ="addDep" value="Add" onclick = "add()" </td>
         <td> <input type="button" id ="deleteDep" value="Delete" onclick = "deleteRow(this)"  </td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
         <td> Child </td>
         <td> 2008-23-06 </td>
         <td> female </td>
         <td> <input type="button" id ="addDep" value="Add" onclick = "add()"</td>
         <td>  <input type="button" id ="deleteDep" value="Delete" onclick = "deleteRow(this)" </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
```

Comment: @gdoron Might want to look at the HTML code ;=) `onclick = "deleteRow(this)"`

Comment: @gdoron that the problem with edits ;=)

Comment: does this only happen after you've added a row using your JS code or also after the first initial loading of the page?

Comment: @Makkes - It also happens after the first initial loading of the page.

Comment: I can't reproduce this behaviour using the code you've posted - neither in Firefox nor Chrome.

Comment: Works fine http://jsfiddle.net/wFtse/1/ Also your markup had some issue with **input tag not closed properly**.. but that shouldn't be causing this issue. Post more details on how to reproduce this issue.

Comment: @yogsma You will also want to use a class for your "addDep" and "deleteDep" values. The id selector is used for a single, unique element. The class selector is used on several elements. More info [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_id_class.asp).

Answer (score 70, accepted):

JavaScript with a few modifications:

```
function deleteRow(btn) {
  var row = btn.parentNode.parentNode;
  row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
}
```

And the HTML with a little difference:

```
<table id="dsTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Relationship Type</td>
      <td>Date of Birth</td>
      <td>Gender</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Spouse</td>
      <td>1980-22-03</td>
      <td>female</td>
      <td><input type="button" value="Add" onclick="add()"/></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Child</td>
      <td>2008-23-06</td>
      <td>female</td>
      <td><input type="button" value="Add" onclick="add()"/></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"/></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: jQuery has a nice function that selects the closest element to remove. It saves on needing to hardcode parent selections.

Comment: Also true, but jQuery is an additional 32K of code, even is compressed and gzipped.

Comment: +1 for recognizing that. But you should never be hosting the file anyway. You should use Google’s CDN to host it. I bet a huge majority of people browsing the Internet already have it on their computer from another site, if not from Google.

Comment: row.parentNode.remove(row); should become row.parentNode.removeChild(row);

Comment: if I use this solve returned error about absent property: "main:370 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined
    at deleteRow (main:370)
    at <anonymous>:1:1"

Answer (score 10):

jQuery has a nice function for [removing elements from the DOM](http://api.jquery.com/remove/).

The [closest() function](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) is cool because it will "get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors."

`$(this).closest("tr").remove();`

Each delete button could run that very succinct code with a function call.

Comment: In addition to this for controlling the row removal, jquery can also help bind your row actions so you don't have obtrusive js calls and can instead have this on your buttons `class ="addDep"` (note: id's cannot be used more than once) and then in the js do     `$('.addDep').on('click',add);` and `$('.deleteDep').on('click', deleteRow);`

Comment: closest() is now a native JavaScript function

Answer (score 1):

Lots of good answers, but here is one more ;)

You can add handler for the click to the table

```
<table id = 'dsTable' onclick="tableclick(event)">
```

And then just find out what the target of the event was

```
function tableclick(e) {
    if(!e)
     e = window.event;

    if(e.target.value == "Delete")
       deleteRow( e.target.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex );
}
```

Then you don't have to add event handlers for each row and your html looks neater. If you don't want any javascript in your html you can even add the handler when page loads:

```
document.getElementById('dsTable').addEventListener('click',tableclick,false);
```

​​

Here is working code: http://jsfiddle.net/hX4f4/2/

Answer (score 0):

I would try formatting your table correctly first off like so:

I cannot help but thinking that formatting the table could at the very least not do any harm.

```
<table>
   <thead>
      <th>Header1</th>
      ......
   </thead>
   <tbody>
       <tr><td>Content1</td>....</tr>
       ......
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You might want to check your own code for errors before posting an answer like this. You cannot place any data inside `<tr></tr>`. The result is usually that the data ends up being displayed before the `<table>`.

Comment: @Perplexor Yes yes, its a silly syntax error. Its easy to criticize from an armchair.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/uluzaq/1) using jQuery. Tested on all the browsers. Here, we have to click the rows in order to delete it with beautiful effect. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using jQuery. What you are doing right now is easy to achieve without jQuery, but as you will want new features and more functionality, jQuery will save you a lot of time. I would also like to mention that you shouldn't have multiple DOM elements with the same ID in one document. In such case use class attribute.

html:

```
<table id="dsTable">
  <tr>
     <td> Relationship Type </td>
     <td> Date of Birth </td>
     <td> Gender </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td> Spouse </td>
     <td> 1980-22-03 </td>
     <td> female </td>
     <td> <input type="button" class="addDep" value="Add"/></td>
     <td> <input type="button" class="deleteDep" value="Delete"/></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
     <td> Child </td>
     <td> 2008-23-06 </td>
     <td> female </td>
     <td> <input type="button" class="addDep" value="Add"/></td>
     <td> <input type="button" class="deleteDep" value="Delete"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

javascript:

```
$('body').on('click', 'input.deleteDep', function() {
   $(this).parents('tr').remove();  
});
```

Remember that you need to reference jQuery:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>`

Here a working jsfiddle example:
http://jsfiddle.net/p9dey/1/

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to delete the particular row of table

```
   <td>
 <asp:ImageButton ID="imgDeleteAction" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/trash.png"  OnClientClick="DeleteRow(this);return false;"/>
 </td>
function DeleteRow(element) {
        document.getElementById("tableID").deleteRow(element.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex);
          
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this for insert

```
 var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  var row = table.insertRow(0);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  cell1.innerHTML = "NEW CELL1";
  cell2.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";
```

and this for delete

```
document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(0);
```

Answer (score -1):

Yeah It is working great
but i have to delete from localstorage too, when user click button , here is my code

```
function RemoveRow(id) {
    // event.target will be the input element.
    // console.log(id)
    let td1 = event.target.parentNode; 
    let tr1 = td1.parentNode; 
    tr1.parentNode.removeChild(tr1);// the row to be removed
    // const books = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("books"));
    // const newBooks= books.filter(book=> book.id !== books.id);
    // console.log(books, newBooks)
    // localStorage.setItem("books", JSON.stringify(newBooks));
}

// function RemoveRow(btn) {
//     var row = btn.parentNode.parentNode;
//     row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
//   }
```

### button tag

```
class Display {
    add(book) {
        console.log('Adding to UI');
        let tableBody = document.getElementById('tableBody')
        let uiString = `<tr class="tableBody" id="tableBody" data-id="${book.id}">
                            <td id="search">${book.name}</td>
                            <td>${book.author}</td>
                            <td>${book.type}</td>
                            <td><input type="button" value="Delete Row" class="btn btn-outline-danger" onclick="RemoveRow(this)"></td>
                        </tr>`;
        tableBody.innerHTML += uiString;

        // save the data to the browser's local storage -----
        const books = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("books"));
        // console.log(books);
        if (!books.some((oldBook) => oldBook.id === book.id)) books.push(book);
        localStorage.setItem("books", JSON.stringify(books));

    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Hi I would do something like this:

```
var id = 4; // inital number of rows plus one
function addRow(){
   // add a new tr with id 
   // increment id;
}

function deleteRow(id){
   $("#" + id).remove();
}
```

and i would have a  table like this:

```
<table id = 'dsTable' >
      <tr id=1>
         <td> Relationship Type </td>
         <td> Date of Birth </td>
         <td> Gender </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id=2>
         <td> Spouse </td>
         <td> 1980-22-03 </td>
         <td> female </td>
         <td> <input type="button" id ="addDep" value="Add" onclick = "add()" </td>
         <td> <input type="button" id ="deleteDep" value="Delete" onclick = "deleteRow(2)"  </td>
      </tr>
       <tr id=3>
         <td> Child </td>
         <td> 2008-23-06 </td>
         <td> female </td>
         <td> <input type="button" id ="addDep" value="Add" onclick = "add()"</td>
         <td>  <input type="button" id ="deleteDep" value="Delete" onclick = "deleteRow(3)" </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
```

Also if you want you can make a loop to build up the table. So it will be easy to build the table. The same you can do with edit:)