# How do I change the select id's name after adding table rows?

Tags: javascript, html, insert, cells

In the table I have two selects, both are getting the values from database.
When pressing add button to add a new row, I want to change select id's name to be 
`facility2, currency2
 facility3, currency3`
and so on. But I do not know how to change them.

This is the table I have created:

```
<table id="tableInformation">
  <tr>
    <td><label>No</label></td>
    <td><label>Facility</label></td>
    <td><label>Currency</label></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><label>1</label></td>
    <td><div id="facility">
        <select id="facility1" name="facility">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="AL">AL</option>
          <option value="BL">BL</option>
          <option value="CL">CL</option>
        </select>
     </td>
     <td><div id="currency">
        <select id="currency1" name="currency">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="idr">IDR</option>
          <option value="usd">USD</option>
          <option value="aud">AUD</option>
          <option value="jpy">JPY</option>
        </select>
     </td>
     <td><input type="button" id="btnAddRows" value=" + "
          onclick=\'addRows()\' />
  </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
```

And this is the javascript:

```
function addRows() {
    var table = document.getElementById('tableInformation');
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var iteration = rowCount -1;
    var numbers = iteration +1;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
    var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

    // Cell for number
    var cell = row.insertCell(0);
    var label = document.createElement('label');
    label.textContent = numbers;
    cell.appendChild(label);

    for(var i=1; i<colCount; i++) {

        var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
        newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;
        //alert(table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML);
        //alert(newcell.childNodes);

    }

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lots of ways to do this. Here's a small addition to what you already have.

Add:

```
.replace(/id="(.+)1"/, 'id="$1' + rowCount + '"')
```

...to:

```
table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML
```

---

EXPLANATION: You're copying the HTML from each cell of the first row into the new row. The `innerHTML` property on the cell object is a string. So use the string `replace` function to modify that string before applying it to the new cell.

The `replace` function, as applied here, replaces the number 1 in the `id` attribute value to whatever the new row number is, using the variable `rowCount`.

The `replace` function pattern *(first argument)* looks for the regular expression pattern: `/id="(.+)1"/`,

- A string starting with `id="`,
- Then capture one or more characters of any kind `(.+)`,
- And a number 1 followed by a quote `1"`.

...for example `id="currency1"`.

The `$1` in the replacement *(second argument)* provides the value of the text captured in the first set of parentheses, in this case: `(.+)`.

(Not used here but `$2` would capture the second set, `$3` would capture the third set, etc. And if parentheses are nested, outer parentheses are captured before inner parentheses.)

Here's the resulting `for` block:

```
for(var i=1; i<colCount; i++) {
  var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
  newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML.replace(/id="(.+)1"/, 'id="$1' + rowCount + '"');
}
```

[JSFiddle example.](https://jsfiddle.net/BloodyKnuckles/rss3bdxf/)

Comment: Oh thanks. I never thought using replace would be this working. And I am aware that I must careful to use replace because it would change the value if I had #1 instead of the id. One more question, is it working for remove the row using the replace?

Comment: Are you wanting to know how to remove a row? If so, read this: [Add/delete row from a table](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13354190/2743458) . If I misunderstand, please elaborate, maybe ask a new question if it's not the same topic.

Comment: I already done with the remove before I found the answer of my case here. Remove function is working just cannot change the number, for ex: when you added row three times, then you removed number two, the last row id's name would be #2 not #3. I tried your trick using replace but it is not changing. Yeah, better I ask a new question. Thank you.