# deleting a row from a table

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to remove a row from a html table using javascript. I know their is a function DOM function that deletes the row but I have my table in a form so when i delete the row it deletes the form to so my buttons do not work. Any ideas to solve this problem?

`

```html
<table style="width:100%" id = "table" >
  <tr>
    <th>Ticket number</th>
    <th>Class</th>
    <th>Meal</th>
    <th>Seat Number</th>
    <th>Price</th>

  </tr>
  <%while(r.next()){ %>
  <tr>
    <td align="center"><form method="post" action="/AirportServer/html/Purchased.jsp">
    <input type="radio" name="Flight-Num" value = "<%=r.getString("ticket_unique_num") %>">
    <%=r.getString("ticket_unique_num") %> </td>
    <td align="center"><%=r.getString("class")%></td>
    <td align="center"><%=r.getString("meal") %></td>
     <td align="center"><%=r.getString("seat_number") %></td>
      <td align="center"><%=r.getString("fare") %></td>
     </tr>
    <%} %>
    <button type="submit">Reserve Ticket</button> 
</form>
</table>
<button onclick="filter()">Sort By low to High</button>
```

```
function filter(){

    var x = document.getElementById("table");
    x.deleteRow(1);

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add/delete row from a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13241005/add-delete-row-from-a-table)

Comment: by default buttons are of type submit, so you have to add the type `<button type="button" onclick="filter()">Sort By low to High</button>`

Answer (score 1):

You should try and change the id from table to something that is unique. Specifically change the following lines:
`<table style="width:100%" id = "table" >` and update this one to reflect the previous snippet `getElementById("table")`

One other thing you should try, is to close the `form` tag *after* the `table` tag

Answer (score 0):

You can place your `<form>` outside of the `<table>` and refer to it using the `form=""` attribute on your inputs.

```
<form name="myForm" action="/foo" method="POST"></form>

<table>
    <tr>
        <input type="text" form="myForm">
    </tr>
</table>

<button type="submit" form="myForm">Submit</button>
```